# Creating an URL without global variables

Tags: php

I have a code like this below, which gives me a **$link** that equals to: **http://mydomain.com/image/photo.JPG**

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['item'][$i]))
{
    $path = dirname(__FILE__).'/image/'.basename($_SESSION['item'][$i]);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_SESSION['item'][$i], $path)) 
        global $url;

    if ( $url )
    {
        $link = $url.'/image/'.basename($_SESSION['item'][$i]);
        echo "<td><img src='" . $link . "' width='50' height='50' /></td>";
    }
}
```

I wonder, how should I properly ommit using global variable here to achieve the same result.

**UPDATE**

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_SESSION['item'][$i], $path))
{
    $link = 'image/'.basename($_SESSION['item'][$i]);  
    echo "<td><img src='" . $link . "' /></td>";
}
```

This modification doesn't show any letter. It seems that if block doesn't execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well why are you using `global` in the first place? Its not apparent from the snippet you provided as there is no reason to use it in this code alone.

If its in a function pass `$url` as an argument... if its something else then we will need the details of usage.

In regards to Col. Shrapnel's answer if you omit the first `/` youll get a link relative to the page accessed. Which as far as i can tell is what youre after:

`$link = 'image/'.basename($_SESSION['item'][$i]);`

Comment: Eh? Reptitive how? `$url` i assume is the url accessed so if he wants images to be accessed realtive to that url he needs to omit your first slash - on the other hand if images is at the document root and thats where things are going then what you provided was fine. But im not sure how either is repetitive - care to elaborate?

Comment: Oh wait i bet that was a typo and you meant "relative". and yeah I have to agree :-)

Comment: It is not inside any function. I just need full url, not relative path. This is an example i've found somewhere on the net. I'am a very beginner in PHP language, and yes, i assume it's a weird code.

Comment: So what is `$url` supposed to be? and where are you getting its value from?

Comment: Nah, the weird and simple answer is: nowhere. See an __UPDATE__ in the post please.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can

```
$link = '/image/'.basename($_SESSION['item'][$i]);
```

But your code is damn weird. Took me a hour to understand